# Importing npm .scss into Meteor App

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I've installed meteorhacks:npm and fourseven:scss to have npm and scss in my Meteor app and it's working fine.  I've installed Bourbon via npm, but I can't figure out how to import it into my .scss

I've tried `@import '/node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.scss';` and get the following error:

```
While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target
   web.browser):
   /simple-todos-angular.scss: Scss compiler error: File to
   import:
   /node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.scss
   not found in file:
   /Users/ChrisWilliams/sites/other_sites/simple-todos-angular/{}/simple-todos-angular.scss
```

Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: I was able to solve this particular problem using https://github.com/wolvesio/meteor-bourbon and not using npm.

Comment: I believe Meteor 1.3 now comes with npm prepackaged.

Comment: i am using Meteor 1.3 and ionic 2 npm package and want to export scss from node_modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix. Just add the following to your project:

meteor npm install --save tether
meteor add fourseven:scss
meteor add orgztion:meteor-global-tether

Works with the latest version of Meteor. 
$ cat .meteor/release 
METEOR@1.4.2.3